# No overload matches 'Slice(UInt8)#+' with type Slice(UInt8) when running code

Tags: crystal-lang

I'm new to Crystal and came across the error `no overload matches 'Slice(UInt8)#+' with type Slice(UInt8)` when running the following code,

```
require "openssl"
NAME = "Boy"

cipher = OpenSSL::Cipher.new("AES-256-CBC")
cipher.encrypt
key = cipher.random_key
iv = cipher.random_iv

# Username

encrypted_name = cipher.update(NAME) + cipher.final
puts encrypted_name

decipher = OpenSSL::Cipher.new("AES-256-CBC")
decipher.decrypt
decipher.key = key
decipher.iv = iv

# Username

plain_name = decipher.update(encrypted_name) + decipher.final

puts plain_name
```

Any help is appreciated. The online ver is [here](https://play.crystal-lang.org/#/r/88gp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the line that fails compilation you're "adding" two slices together.

According to this spec:

https://github.com/crystal-lang/crystal/blob/master/spec/std/openssl/cipher_spec.cr

You basically have to add that to an IO first then you can convert it to a string.

ex: https://gist.github.com/rdp/349161fd5b10208dc7445fb5d9beefae (though it seems to only work locally not on crystal play)

Comment: Ah, I see. Thank you very much!